# Change columns in several dfs depending on name of df in a loop (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I want to change the column names in several dfs in a loop, where the new column names depend on the name of the df:

```
library(dplyr)

# A simple example of my data:
dataframe_AA <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(1:3),
  var2 = sample(1:3),
  var3 = sample(1:3))

dataframe_AB <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(1:3),
  var2 = sample(1:3),
  var3 = sample(1:3))


dfs <- list(dataframe_AA, dataframe_AB)
combinations <- c("AA", "AB")
oldnames = c("var1", "var2", "var3")

for (df in seq_along(dfs)) {
  for (combi in combinations) {
    newnames = paste(oldnames, substr = substring(combi,1,2), sep = "_")
    df <- df %>% rename_at(vars(oldnames), ~newnames)
  }
  }



#Expected outcome:
names(dataframe_AA)
[1] "var1_AA" "var2_AA" "var3_AA"

names(dataframe_AB)
[1] "var1_AB" "var2_AB" "var3_AB"
```

`newnames` is successfully created inside the loop, but then I receive the error message: `Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"`

Doing everything outside a loop works, however:

```
df = dataframe_AA
combi = "AA"
newnames = paste(oldnames, substr = substring(combi,1,2), sep = "_")
df <- df %>% rename_at(vars(oldnames), ~newnames)

print(names(df))
[1] "var1_AA" "var2_AA" "var3_AA"
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here and how I can make it work in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get dataframes in a list and then paste new variables based on name of the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)



temp <- imap(mget(ls(pattern = "dataframe_.*")), function(x, y) 
          x %>% rename_at(vars(oldnames), ~paste0(., sub(".*_", "_", y))))
```

`temp` is list of dataframes with changed names, to get the individual dataframes in global environment we can use  `list2env`.

```
list2env(temp, .GlobalEnv)

names(dataframe_AA)
#[1] "var1_AA" "var2_AA" "var3_AA"
names(dataframe_AB)
#[1] "var1_AB" "var2_AB" "var3_AB"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately I get the error `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x The columns `var1`, `var2`, `var3` don't exist.`

Comment: @JuliaP. In that case please give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) of your data.

Comment: Ah yes of course. I made an edit. Hope it becomes more clear like this.

Comment: @JuliaP. Thank you, for providing an example. It was a scoping issue. I used an anonymous function to solve that. Updated the answer, you can check now.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! It works perfectly. I only had to add `library(purrr)`  in addition to `dplyr` to make it work.